# React + Reflux - Issue with queue and timeout for components sharing the same store

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I have a component like so,

I've refactored it for the example to not use valueLink to help illustrate the problem.

In this example, I have a Field component, rendered multiple times (3) all bound to the same property in the store.  The concept is pretty simple, when input changes in one, it will be reflected in the others.

The problem comes if you type really fast (bash a few keys in) and the events get queued then ends in a loops where each component is updating based on an earlier state update from another component. If you type slowly, i guess more slowly that the tick timeout on the queue, it works fine.

A similar symptom can be observed using value link. But it's doing the same thing pretty much so I'd expect that.

```
var App = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return  <Field dataItemName="PropertyA" />
        <Field dataItemName="PropertyA" />
        <Field dataItemName="PropertyA" />;
  }
});

var RecordStore = Reflux.createStore({
    mixins: [StateMixin],
    listenables: [FormActions, RecordActions],

    init: function () {        
    },

    getInitialState: function () {        
        return { PropertyA : 'test' };
    },

    valueChanged: function (newVal, propName) {        
        var o = {};
        if (newVal !== this.state[propName].value) {
            o[propName] = newVal;           
            this.setState(o);
        }
    }
});

var Field = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.ListenerMixin],
    getInitialState: function () {
        return ({           
            value: RecordStore.state[this.props.dataItemName].value          
        })
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.listenTo(RecordStore[this.props.dataItemName], this.updateValue);              
    },
    updateValue: function (value) {       
        this.setState({ value: value.value });
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {     
        return  nextState.value != this.state.value;
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {       
        RecordActions.valueChanged(this.state.value, this.props.dataItemName);
    },
    handleInput: function (event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    },
    render: function () {                  
       return (
         <div className='form-group'>
           <label htmlFor={this._reactInternalInstance._rootNodeID+'_input'}>{this.props.label}</label>
           <input className="form-control" value={this.state.value} id={this._reactInternalInstance._rootNodeID+'_input'} onChange={this.handleInput} />          
         </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I've thought about using my own timeout before updating the value in the store, i.e. waiting until the user has finished input; but I wondered whether the is anything in the framework/lib to handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's an answer for anyone looking for a solution using timeout.

The problem can be traced back to React's drainQueue that invokes the remaining items in the queue.  In this solution, I simply want to defer putting the updateValue on the queue until we're sure the velocity of the events being created by bashing the keyboard has finished.

By changing the `componentDidUpdate` to use a timeout (i think it just needs to be > 0) means that each keystroke wont trigger an event, negating the problem I originally asked about.

```
componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) { 
     **var _self = this;
     clearTimeout(_self.state.inputtimer);        
    _self.state.inputtimer = setTimeout(function () { RecordActions.valueChanged(_self.state.value, _self.props.dataItemName);},50);**
}
```

That appears to have done the job.  Any comments or other solutions are very welcome.  I'd prefer to have done it using valueLink (which i think i still can i think) and could create a mixin for the timeout i guess.

This is the drainQueue func for reference.

```
function drainQueue() {
    if (draining) {
        return;
    }
    var timeout = setTimeout(cleanUpNextTick);
    draining = true;

    var len = queue.length;
    while(len) {
        currentQueue = queue;
        queue = [];
        while (++queueIndex < len) {
            currentQueue[queueIndex].run();
        }
        queueIndex = -1;
        len = queue.length;
    }
    currentQueue = null;
    draining = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

thanks